# Insert bigquery results in Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, cloud, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I want to insert bigquery results into cloudSql.I want to get idea that how i can get the datatype of the table cell.So that i can insert the row in cloud sql with proper data type.

What is the correct way of inserting bigquery results into cloud sql table with proper datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Big query API have methods that will give the metadata of the tables returned in response.